# NetSuite: PO Rate in Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to pull the PO Rate in a Saved Transaction search. This is a built in field on the Sales Order. When I pull it in to the search, it shows no data for Sales Orders that clearly have it if you go to the record. I have tried pulling it by selecting the Field and by using a formula to pull the Field ID (porate). Nothing seems to work. These are Sales Orders without a PO at this time, but the Po Rate field is populated and we need it extracted.

We need this for an upload of data. I know this seems like an easy task - and we thought it would be. Anything you can advise is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the line item has "Created Po" i.e. it has special order lines or Drop ship line items , the field "Po rate" has value and it does gets pulled into Search Results.

Also, there are extra lines in search results for shipping and taxes which will not have "Po Rates". Also, you may want to apply filter mailline is false, as porate is line item field

Comment: I was aware of the above. The issue I had was that apparently ONLY if you have created PO filled in does PO rate pull into searches. I knew it would if the created PO was filled in but I didn't know it had to be

Comment: Yeah it has to be populated if it has to show value in search results